# Android. Calling dismiss on a dialog

Tags: android

When you call `dismiss()` on a dialog, besides hiding it, does it also remove it from memory? Does it remove all the Objects that were placed inside the dialog, like `ImageViews`, `Buttons`, etc, from memory?

Is there a way i could free up the memory of these objects myself, and not wait for the Garbage Collector to do it's job?

Comment: Why u need that!! let system do what it wants

Comment: I'm having memory leaks ... Out Of Memory exceptions thrown and i need to free up as much memory as i can. And i wasn't sure what the function does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, i believe that `dismiss()` just hides it.

[Here is the reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog)

`removeDialog(int)` will clear the state.

Comment: Your memory leaks could be caused from something else. If you can narrow it down a little, come by here and let us help you again.

Comment: yeah, that's my next post question. I'll post it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In java memory can only be free by Garbage Collector and you can only make all that object to be null so that garbage collector can collect memory to free.

Why do you need this? The entire point of Java is that it takes care of memory management for you. Do you have some obvious memory issues or something?

Comment: Yes i do. It throws out of memory exception quite often

Comment: can you share the code which you think are causing this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Android Developer Documentation say :

> public void dismiss () :
>   Since: API Level 1
>   Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().

Answer (score 1):

Manually `free`ing memory is

1. Not doable in Java. You can allocate memory with `new`, but the Garbage Collector takes care of freeing it
2. A bad idea when you have a Garbage Collector trying to work behind.

`dismiss()` simply hides the dialog. Call `removeDialog(int)` to remove all the references to it and wait for the GC to kick in.