# Android: How to properly remove a dialog

Tags: android, memory-management

I wonder whether a Dialog (or a PopupWindow) gets removed completely after calling
dialog.dismiss();

Someone knows whether I might run into memory issues when creating constantly popups and only dismissing them?

Comment: what is the purpose of that comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542503/android-calling-dismiss-on-a-dialog) post. Since `removeDialog()` has been deprecated in API 13, and it is suggested you use `DialogFramgment` instead, all `FragmentTransaction` methods hold.